# GARCH (sGARCH) with ARFIMA (ARIMA) model in Rugarch equation formula output

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, variance, garch

**Could you please help to write down the exact equation?**

It is clear for Garch part but not clear how to add ARFIMA (1,0,1) or here just ARMA(1,1) in model equation specification.

Should we also type formula for our distrubution type that follows normal here?
How change the equation for same model but with Student-t distrubution ?

[image]